# Cannot read property 'oScroll' of undefined - jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm working with datatables to paginate results loaded from server.

When I import jquery.dataTables.js and jquery.dataTables.css (1.10.2) the browser console displays this error: Cannot read property 'oScroll' of undefined. The problem is in this line :

```
 var scroll = settings.oScroll;
```

it concerns the function recalculating datatables column size :

```
/**
 * This function will make DataTables recalculate the column sizes, based on the data
 * contained in the table and the sizes applied to the columns (in the DOM, CSS or
 * through the sWidth parameter). This can be useful when the width of the table's
 * parent element changes (for example a window resize).
 *  @param {boolean} [bRedraw=true] Redraw the table or not, you will typically want to
 *  @dtopt API
 *  @deprecated Since v1.10
 *
 *  @example
 *    $(document).ready(function() {
 *      var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
 *        "sScrollY": "200px",
 *        "bPaginate": false
 *      } );
 *
 *      $(window).bind('resize', function () {
 *        oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
 *      } );
 *    } );
 */
this.fnAdjustColumnSizing = function ( bRedraw )
{
    var api = this.api( true ).columns.adjust();
    var settings = api.settings()[0];
    var scroll = settings.oScroll;

    if ( bRedraw === undefined || bRedraw ) {
        api.draw( false );
    }
    else if ( scroll.sX !== "" || scroll.sY !== "" ) {
        /* If not redrawing, but scrolling, we want to apply the new column sizes anyway */
        _fnScrollDraw( settings );
    }
};
```

Anyone has an idea about this issue ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is yet another `dataTable()` vs `DataTable()` issue. As you can see, `fnAdjustColumnSizing` is deprecated. And even worse, it does not work with the `DataTable()`-constructor at all.  Solution, either instantiate your table with the old dataTable constructor :

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
```

or, use the **1.10.x** API approach :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   "sScrollY": "200px",
   "bPaginate": false
});

$(window).bind('resize', function () {
   table.columns.adjust().draw(); 
});
```

demo where you can experiment with both -> **http://jsfiddle.net/w6vhusay/**